# How to describe all metrics invariant by $O(3)$ on a given space?

Tags: differential-geometry, homogeneous-spaces, symmetric-spaces

I want to describe all pseudo-Riemannian metrics (symmetric covariant non degenerate 2-tensor fields) invariant by $O(3)$ on different manifolds ($\mathbb R^3$, the sphere $S^2$, and $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[\times S^2$ in priority.

The difficulty depends on the given space, for instance for the sphere I think I have the idea :
Since the sphere is a reductive $O(3)$-homogeneous space $(S^n=\frac{O(n+1)}{O(n)})$, all metrics on the sphere invariant by $O(3)$ are equal to the first fundamental form up to a scalar factor.

For $\mathbb R^3$ it starts to be more challenging (for me at least) since I don't have the same highly simplifying theorems. I first wanted to just classify all metrics on $\mathbb R^3$ and get rid of those that are not invariant by $O(3)$. However "classifiying all metrics on $\mathbb R^3$" is actually really hard.
An other way would be to say : if $q$ is a metric on $\mathbb R^3$, then take a vector $v$, you have a $g \in O(3)$ such that $gv=||v||e_1$ with $e_1$ a canonical unitary vector of $\mathbb R^3$ (because $O(3)$ acts transitively on a sphere). If you want your metric $q$ to be invariant under $O(3)$, then $q(v,v)=q(gv,gv)=||v||^2q(e_1,e_1)$, so all metrics are equal to the euclidian one up to a scalar again.

Then for $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[\times S^2$ it looks even harder to find some tricks.

An easier thing to start may be to look at  $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[\times S^1$.

Thus I would like to know if there is a general method for this problem, and if not, at least some methods (even methods using supplementary hypothesis that we would make if needed are interesting to know about).

Comment: Explain what do you mean by a metric

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I mean a bilinear symmetric non degenerate form

Comment: Edit your question to make things clear (but also state if your form is positive definite).

Comment: @MoisheKohanonstrike I had already edited the first line of my question to make things clear. I'll add that i'm aiming for pseudo-Riemannian metrics (which are not positive definite)

Comment: I'm not editing the title because actually if seomone has a trick for Riemanninan or Lorentzian metrics it is still interesting for me to see it

Comment: You also have to think if what you wrote makes sense (currently it does not). One can talk about a bilinear form on a vector space, but two of your examples are not vector spaces. It is possible that you mean the restriction of a form from the ambient vector space. Or, what you really mean is a tensor field. All in all, your question is unclear.

Comment: Okay I see, I edited it to be "symmetric covariant non degenerate 2-tensor fields" according to the definition of "INTRODUCTION TO GENERAL RELATIVITY, BLACK HOLES, AND COSMOLOGY, Yvonne Choquet-Bruhat, I.5" of pseudo Riemannian metrics

Comment: You seem to be confused between the difference between a norm, metric, and Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$Let’s assume you want Riemannian metrics on $\R^3$ that are invariant under the standard action of $O(3)$. Let $g$ be such a metric. It’s restriction to any sphere centered at $0$ has to be a constant times the standard metric. From here it is not hard to show that the metric in spherical coordinates has to be of the form $$g = (a(r))^2\,dr^2 + (b(r))^2h $$ where $h$ is the standard metric on the sphere.

Comment: I tried to have this result but I'm unsatisfied of my work. It looks all natural but I have difficulty proving that cross terms disappear ($d\phi dr$ and $d\theta dr$), and why a depends only on r. As you say that it should be easy I assume I lack knowledge on the matter. So far i've been taught basic differential geometry, and introductions to Lie algebras, to G-homogeneous groups, and to symmetric spaces. Can you recommand me some books to learn what I need ? Or point at what fields I should brush up on ?

Comment: I found a possible reason for the disappearing of cross terms using the fact that g is 2-covariant, we can write  for $\mu \neq \phi$ and $\phi \rightarrow -\phi$ : $g'_{\mu \phi}=\frac{dx^a}{dx'^\mu}\frac{dx^b}{dx'^\phi}g_{ab}=-g_{\mu \phi}$. And invariance would imply  $g'_{\mu \phi}=g_{\mu \phi}$, so $g_{\mu \phi}=0$.